# Ag-Grid Multi-line Edit with Multi Row Selection

Tags: angular, ag-grid, edit, ag-grid-angular

I want implement multi row edit based on the selected rows, but unfortunatlty I am unable to find any example on ag-grid documentation. Here is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/13E55QtYFyde4eZX) link where I have Multi-line checkboxes on Row groups whenever I selected the rows the selected rows become editable but the issues When I  I focus/edit on any one of the cell all of the other selected editable rows become normal. Is ag-grid provide this feature or is it possible in ag-grid? Thanks!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';
import { RowGroupingModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping';
import { MenuModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/menu';
import { ColumnsToolPanelModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel';
import '@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/core/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [modules]="modules"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
    [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
    (selectionChanged)="gridRowSelectionChanged($event)"
    [groupSelectsChildren]="true"
    [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
    [suppressAggFuncInHeader]="true"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;

  public modules: Module[] = [
    ClientSideRowModelModule,
    RowGroupingModule,
    MenuModule,
    ColumnsToolPanelModule,
  ];
  private columnDefs;
  private defaultColDef;
  private autoGroupColumnDef;
  private rowSelection;
  private rowData: [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        field: 'country',
        rowGroup: true,
        hide: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'gold',
        aggFunc: 'sum',
        editable: true
      },
      {
        field: 'silver',
        aggFunc: 'sum',
        editable: true
      },
      {
        field: 'bronze',
        aggFunc: 'sum',
        editable: true
      },
      {
        field: 'age',
        minWidth: 120,
        checkboxSelection: true,
        aggFunc: 'sum',
      },
      {
        field: 'year',
        maxWidth: 120,
      },
      {
        field: 'date',
        minWidth: 150,
      },
    ];
    this.defaultColDef = {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 100,
    };
    this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
      headerName: 'Athlete',
      field: 'athlete',
      minWidth: 250,
      cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
      cellRendererParams: { checkbox: true },
    };
    this.rowSelection = 'multiple';
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http
      .get('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.rowData = data;
      });
  }

  gridRowSelectionChanged(params) {
  const selectedNodes = params.api.getSelectedNodes();
    selectedNodes.forEach(node => {
      this.gridApi.startEditingCell({
        rowIndex: node.rowIndex,
        colKey: 'gold',
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have been presented with the same pattern by my UX team and am struggling to implement a PoC.

Comment: @jeffeld, I was not able to solve it as the ag-grid doesn't provide a solution for a given problem, and in the case of custom implementation, there are a lot of edge cases that the ag-grid is unable to handle. So we go with full row edit in ag-grid.

Comment: Did you try the suppressRowClickSelection

Answer (score 0):

You can change selected rows data with cellValueChanged event.
for example to make the value of column a same in selected rows ,you only need to edit 1 cell

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/cell-editing/#event-cell-value-changed

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent deselection using grid option `suppressRowClickSelection: true`
Have a look at my example below
https://plnkr.co/edit/1aQyW0NSpjYYPNE2?preview

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get this to work. Add suppressRowClickSelection.

```
<ag-grid-angular ... suppressRowClickSelection  (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)">
```

Then in the component code you watch for changes and update all the other row data with something like this.

```
rowsSelected() {
    return this.gridApi && this.gridApi.getSelectedRows().length > 0;
  }
onCellValueChanged(event) {
    if (event.node.selected && this.rowsSelected()) {
        let editedColumn = event.colDef.field;
        let selectedRows = this.locationgridApi.getSelectedRows();
        if (event.oldValue != event.newValue) {
          selectedRows.forEach(e => {
            e[editedColumn] = event.data[editedColumn];
          });
          this.gridApi.refreshCells();
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log("No rows are selected or the current row is NOT selected")
      }
}
```